# How to position text to bottom left of floated image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an image/icon in the bottom right of a div with text wrapping around it. I've used the tips from this [article](https://css-tricks.com/float-an-element-to-the-bottom-corner/) to get the image in the right position. But, I'm having trouble now getting the text to position at the bottom of the div. It's probably a simple solution that I'm overlooking. Thanks in advance!

```css
.grid-overlay {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}

.grid-icon {
  display: flex;
  fill: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  shape-outside: inset(calc(100% - 30px) 0 0);
}

svg {
    background: green;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-overlay">
  <div class="box">
  <div class="grid-icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 256 512" width="30" title="angle-right">
    <path d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean diam est, laoreet non luctus a.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean diam est.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: reduce the height, use 75% instead of 100%

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your .box would get the text to the bottom aligned with the icon.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Changing .grid-overlay padding to remove to top would make it look like this:

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqzM7.png)

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is I need the text to extend to the width of the `.box`. As if the text is wrapping around the icon.